# How to make test case wait until before() execution finishes?

Tags: node.js, async-await, mocha.js

I am writing tests in nodejs using mocha framework. Since the endpoints that I am testing are asynchronous, I used aync-await concept. But the test case is not waiting for the before() execution part to finish running i.e; the async function and hence showing wrong result for listAll() api.

```
async function fetchContent() {
    const [profile, user] = await Promise.all([api.profiles.list(), api.users.list()])

    params = {userId: user.items[0].id, label: 'Test', profileId: profile.items[0].id, token: authToken}
    testApi = new Api(params)
    testApi.profiles.create(params)
}

before(async () => {
    await fetchContent()
})

describe('Profiles API', () => {
    it('list profiles', done => {
        testApi.profiles.listAll().then(response => {
            console.log('list=', response)
        })
        done()
    })
})
```

Also I tried it() like below but still listAll() doesn't display the profile record that is created as part of before() execution:

```
describe('Profiles API', () => {
    it('list profiles', async () => {
                const response = await testApi.profiles.listAll()
                console.log('list=', response)
})
```

Comment: Inside the function `fetchContent` the last call `testApi.profiles.create(params)` is asynchronous?

Comment: @SamuelVaillant yes create() is aynchronous and so is listAll() in it() test .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `await` for the last call inside `fecthContent` since it's asynchronous, otherwise the tests start before it finish. `beforeEach` allow you to return a promise to wait for its completion (see [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises) docs).

```
async function fetchContent() {
  const [profile, user] = await Promise.all([
    api.profiles.list(),
    api.users.list()
  ]);

  params = {
    userId: user.items[0].id,
    label: "Test",
    profileId: profile.items[0].id,
    token: authToken
  };

  testApi = new Api(params);

  // This call is asynchronous we have to wait
  await testApi.profiles.create(params);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel for mentioning this. I replaced before() with beforeEach() and put await for aync create() and now the test case is working fine;listAll() shows correct response . However I have a doubt -does before() not return the promise as beforeEach()

Comment: @SoC I think both of them support the promise pattern. The issue was related to the lack of wait for the `create` function. With a `before` it should also work as expected.